# how to increase max job count 60 in flutter

Tags: list, flutter

I'm working on list and then convert this list into file and send into server through MultipartRequest.. I send my file many times and data was changed  but suddenly my data will not change .when I check my log where I found this line increase max job count 60 ..I dont have any idea what its mean ..and how I increase my max job count

> code for make file

```
 final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final File file = File('${directory.path}/360feedback.json');
await file.writeAsString(jsonEncode(value));
```

code for file to send on server

```
try {
  var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream(file.openRead()));
  var length = await file.length();
  var uri = Uri.parse("https://ben.kli.pk/api/submitqueries");
  var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
  var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('data', stream, length,
      filename: basename(file.path));
  request.files.add(multipartFile);

  await request.send().then((response) {
    response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
      file.delete();

      print(value);
    });
  }).catchError((e) {
    print(e);
  });
} catch (e) {
  // An error was received
  throw new Exception("GET ERROR $e");
}
```